# How do you get a dataframe to perform a SQL groupby operation on multiple columns?

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
index         Player Team      Matchup   Game_Date WL  Min  PTS  FGM   FGA   FG%  3PM  3PA   3P% FTM FTA    FT%  OREB  DREB  REB  AST  STL  BLK  TOV   PF  Plus_Minus  Triple_Double  Double_Double    FPT   2PA  2PM        2P%
1      John Long  TOR    TOR @ BOS  04/20/1997  W    6    0    0   3.0   0.0    0  1.0   0.0   0   0    0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0         2.0            0.0            1.0   3.00   2.0    0   0.000000
2  Walt Williams  TOR    TOR @ BOS  04/20/1997  W   29    7    3   9.0  33.3    1  2.0  50.0   0   0    0.0   0.0   3.0  3.0  2.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  5.0        20.0            0.0            1.0  21.25   7.0    2  28.571429
3       Todd Day  BOS  BOS vs. TOR  04/20/1997  L   36   22    8  17.0  47.1    4  8.0  50.0   2   2  100.0   0.0   6.0  6.0  4.0  0.0  0.0  3.0  2.0       -21.0            0.0            1.0  37.50   9.0    4  44.444444
4  Doug Christie  TOR    TOR @ BOS  04/20/1997  W   39   27    8  19.0  42.1    3  9.0  33.3   8   8  100.0   0.0   1.0  1.0  5.0  3.0  1.0  0.0  2.0        30.0            0.0            1.0  46.75  10.0    5  50.000000
5    Brett Szabo  BOS  BOS vs. TOR  04/20/1997  L   25    5    1   4.0  25.0    0  0.0     0   3   4   75.0   1.0   2.0  3.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  5.0       -11.0            0.0            1.0  11.75   4.0    1  25.000000
```

I would like to create a dataframe that groups on team and game_date. I am trying the following code:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Game_Date', 'Team', 'Matchup', 'WL'], as_index=False)['Min', 'PTS', 'FGM', 'FGA', '3PM', '3PA', 'FTM', 'FTA',
                                                         'OREB', 'DREB', 'REB', 'AST', 'STL', 'BLK', 'TOV', '2PM', '2PA',
                                                         'PF'].sum()
```

However, when I run it, I get the following dataframe:

```
Game_Date Team      Matchup WL     Min    PTS    FGM      FGA    3PM      3PA    OREB     DREB      REB      AST     STL     BLK     TOV    2PM      2PA       PF
04/11/2018  DEN    DEN @ MIN  L   21966  12552   4707  11506.0   2615   5230.0  1046.0   3138.0   4184.0   2615.0   523.0   523.0  1046.0   2092   6276.0   2092.0
04/11/2018  MEM    MEM @ OKC  L  125520  64329  23012  47593.0   6799  16213.0  4707.0  16736.0  21443.0  11506.0  4707.0  1046.0  6799.0  16213  31380.0  11506.0
04/11/2018  MIN  MIN vs. DEN  W   40271  20397   7322  15167.0    523   2092.0  1046.0   4707.0   5753.0   2615.0  1569.0  1046.0  2092.0   6799  13075.0   4184.0
04/11/2018  NOP  NOP vs. SAS  W  124997  63806  27196  46024.0   2615   9937.0  5753.0  20920.0  26673.0  15690.0  5753.0  2615.0  9937.0  24581  36087.0  10460.0
04/11/2018  OKC  OKC vs. MEM  W  126043  71651  24581  44455.0  10460  22489.0  4184.0  19351.0  23535.0  16736.0  4184.0  1569.0  7322.0  14121  21966.0  12029.0
```

Why is it grouping incorrectly?

Comment: exactly how is it grouping incorrectly?

Comment: It should just be summing all the stats for each team on each day.

Comment: isn't that what it's doing?

Comment: No each team only plays 240 minutes total between each of its players